# How to evaluate $\int \sqrt{\sin^{-1}(\sqrt{\phi})} d\phi $?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

**How do I go about solving the below integral?** $$I_1=\int \sqrt{\sin^{-1}(\sqrt{\phi})} d\phi $$

---

Background:

I came across the simpler version of this, which required me to evaluate:
$$\int\sin^{-1}(\sqrt{\phi})d\phi$$
I got the solution for this: $$\big[\sin^{-1}(\sqrt{\phi})\big(\phi-\frac{1}{2}\big) + \frac{\sqrt{\phi(1-\phi)}}{2}\big] + C$$

But I still don't see this helping me solve the original question (i.e. $I_1$).

---

**Note:**

[image]

*Wolfram Alpha gives this solution, but I want to know how to arrive at it.*

---

Edit:

I did a substitution $\phi = \sin^2(\psi)$ to get:

$$\int \sqrt{\psi}\sin(2\psi)d\psi$$

Now I'm stuck...

Comment: Do you know anything about Fresnel integrals?

Comment: Not much @LuigiD. . Was reading about them on Wiki right now.. I mainly wish to know the process of solving this integral from step one to the finish... Doesn't matter if I can;t fully understand the process; I'm still in the process of learning..

Comment: Taking WolframAlpha's result as a hint, I would combine integration by parts and substitution, together with the knowledge that $\int \cos{(\sin^{-1}{(x)})} dx = \frac{1}{2}(x\sqrt{1 - x^2} + \sin^{-1}{(x)}) + C.$

Comment: The obvious substitution is $\phi=\sin^2t$, followed by $t=u^2$.

Comment: "Obvious"...such a dangerous term in mathematics.

Comment: @Lucian OMG I did the same thing and updated my answer... Thanks for the follow up tip though!

Comment: @crash Here I think it is a bit obvious :)

Comment: @Kugelblitz Sure. My point is that rarely much good comes out of using such an adjective.

Comment: @crash Agreed...

Comment: @crash: [And your point is... ?](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086617) :-$)$

Comment: @Lucian Correct link? Made me laugh whatever it is but I don't get its relevance unless it's some sort of cheeky rejoinder :)

Comment: @crash I guess he's implying that he's living dangerously...as you explicitly pointed out.

Comment: @Kugelblitz If that is Lucian living dangerously, he needs to get out more haha. Okay time for bed. Night all!

Comment: Anyway, thank you @Lucian! You seem to help me with every integral I come across :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With $t=\arcsin\sqrt\phi$, we have $\phi=\sin^2t$ and 
$$I_1=\int \sqrt{\arcsin\sqrt{\phi}}\,d\phi =\int2\sqrt t\sin t\cos t\,dt=\int\sqrt t\sin 2t\,dt.$$
Now, $2t=p^2$, $dt=p\,dp$, and
$$I_1=\frac1{\sqrt2}\int p^2\sin p^2\,dp.$$
By parts,

$$I_1=-\frac1{2\sqrt2}\int p\left(\cos p^2\right)'dp=-\frac1{2\sqrt2}p\cos p^2+\frac1{2\sqrt2}\int \cos p^2\,dp,$$

then we need a Fresnel integral.

Comment: i was writing the same answer! (+1)

Comment: Yea... so how do we proceed?

Comment: @Kugelblitz: proceed what ? It's done ! ($p=\sqrt{2\arcsin\sqrt\phi}$)

Comment: How do you use the fresnel Integral now sir? Could you get it to the form obtained by Wolfram Alpha?

Comment: @Kugelblitz does Wolfram Alpha say what is that $C(.)$ function?

Comment: @Kugelblitz: you should be able to recognize that my solution is that of Wolfram by substituting $p$. That's your part of the job.

Comment: @Math-fun Yes it does; it says it's the C Fresnel Integral

Comment: @YvesDaoust Sir, I realised that only a while later; specifically after you edited your comment to include the substitution (Sorry; sometimes obvious things fly by your head, especially if you're as inexperienced as me with integrals..). I have trouble with the $/pi$ in the WA expression; I can't see it in your solution. That's my doubt now.. (Also, Sorry for bothering you with possibly trivial doubts; as a tenth grader I'm unfortunately inexperienced with this area of math.. I promise (myself) to get better)

Comment: @Kugelblitz: This depends how exactly the $C$ function is defined. You will notice that I didn't use the $C$ notation, for this very reason.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Never mind sir; I managed to get that form to that of yours. Thank you for your help!